# Git subtree push returns remote unpack failed

Tags: git, github, git-subtree

this is my situation

1. I added a external repo using `git subtree add -P dir/ externalrepo master`.
2. From there I create a branch locally (`git checkout -b newbranch`)
3. Made some changes, I committed and pushed them
4. Now I just want to add those changes to the external repo with `git subtree push -P dir/ externalrepo master` but this is the outcome

```
git push using:  externalrepo master
Enumerating objects: 24, done.
fatal: remote error: want 585cc138094f5003142f0cb5a40f0f56ecd1facf not valid
error: remote unpack failed: eof before pack header was fully read
To github.com:user/externalrepo.git
 ! [remote rejected]   88c2aa24aea0bf7d7942209f31215b003cdf5e67 -> master (failed)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:user/externalrepo.git'
```

I dont know how to add the changes to the external repo

Answer (score 0):

The issue had to do with being in a partial clone. I guess `git subtree push` checks all the history and given that it was a partial clone, the whole history was not available. The solution is either get all the history with `git pull --unshallow` or if that doesn't work try removing the partial clone filter [following these steps](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/git/partial_clone.html#remove-partial-clone-filtering). Or, the second option is from a different repository, one without partial cloning (it still can have sparse checkouts activated) try to do the `git subtree push`.